# Android - Lottie Compose clickable foward/reverse

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

I just move my old project to Jetpack Compose.
I want to create a lottie compose component :

- Animation is launched on click of the lottie element;
- Has a checked boolean that manage the lottie animation => if Checked the lottie is at the end of the animation, if not checked it is at the start;

For moment I was able to make a clickable lottie Component which on click animate forward and on another click backward.
I am struggled on how to play lottie animation from the end in reverse mode.

Here is my code :

```
private fun LottieAnim(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    isChecked: Boolean = true,
    res: Int
) {
    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(res))
    var checked by remember { mutableStateOf(isChecked) }
    var isPlaying by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
        composition = composition,
        restartOnPlay = false,
        isPlaying = isPlaying,
        speed = if (checked) -1f else 1f,
        clipSpec = LottieClipSpec.Progress(0f, 1f)
    )

    LottieAnimation(
        composition,
        progress = {
            progress
        },
        modifier = modifier.clickable {
            isPlaying = true
        }
    )

    LaunchedEffect(progress){
        if (progress == 1f) {
            Log.i("INFO", "Animation End")
            isPlaying = false
            checked = true
        }
        if (progress == 0f){
            Log.i("INFO", "Animation Start")
            isPlaying = false
            checked = false
        }
    }
}
```

In this case even if isChecked is true it come back to false because progress start at 0f and move checked to false.
Do you have any idea how to help me ? Is there otherway to handle "lottie animation is at start/end" than using progress ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of `progress` only when `isPlaying` is `true`, and then change the `checked` value when the animation is finished (1.0 or 0.0).

Something like:

```
    LaunchedEffect(progress) {
        if (isPlaying &&
            (progress == 1.0f || progress == 0.0f)
        ){
            isPlaying = false
            checked = !checked
        }
    }
```

[image]